# C++: direct accessors or access functions within class?

Tags: c++, class, accessor

I have two versions of a class named 'vertex', one that uses direct accessors for the coordinates:

```
struct vertex
{
    // Coordinates
    std::array<double, 3> coords;

    // Direct accessors
    double & x;
    double & y;
    double & z;

    // Constructor
    template<typename... T> vertex(T &&... coordinates) :
        coords{{ std::forward<T>(coordinates)... }},
        x( coords[0] ), y( coords[1] ), z( coords[2] )
    { }
};
```

and other that uses access functions:

```
struct vertex
{
    // Coordinates
    std::array<double, 3> coords;

    // Access functions
    double & x() { return coords[0]; }
    double & y() { return coords[1]; }
    double & z() { return coords[2]; }

    // Constructor
    template<typename... T> vertex(T &&... coordinates) :
        coords{{ std::forward<T>(coordinates)... }}
    { }
};
```

Which approach is better for this specific case? I would appreciate any other suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: What would "better" be in this case?

Comment: Just saying: 1 vertex, many vertices.

Comment: See also: [Why use getters and setters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters).

Comment: thanks @pwny! Sorry for my bad english

Comment: @rogerlga Oh that wasn't the point, it's not my first language either.  It was more of a tip in case someone else reads your code so they have an easier time understanding.  We can never stop learning!

Comment: @pwny: this is actually just one vertex, not many of them, read the code.

Comment: @sharvey The question was edited, the class name used to be vertice.  Thanks for your completely relevant comment assuming I didn't read the code.  Maybe if you had followed your own advice, you'd have realized I must have read it, considering I wrote an answer.

Comment: @mfontanini mainly better performance, i.e. a call to an inline function would behave pretty much the same as a direct access?

Comment: @rogerlga: there never isn't the better solution. All depends on what you are actually using vertices for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally would go through functions, for encapsulation purposes.

But this is a quite particular case, because you are dealing with vertices. If you plan to manipulate a lot of those objects (rendering or trasforming meshes), then direct access has some benefits in term of performances.

Some graphic libraries use direct access (and some books suggests too) for vector-like operations in real-time environments where efficiency it's a must.

Have a look at [Ogre::Vector3](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/OgreVector3_8h_source.html) for example.

Despite that I wouldn't do what you are doing in your first solution. Like other said 
you are doubling the used space for no reason (for eventually a lot of vertices).
From my point of view, in a context of high performance this could be the best vertex:

```
class Vertex
{
public:
   double X;
   double Y;
   double Z;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I think getters are better. First approach creates objects of bigger size for no real benefit.

Comment: This!  Assuming you're on a 64-bit machine, those reference members double the size of each vertex.  This counts double as vertices are something you typically have a lot of.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the function - it allows you to change your mind more easily in the future. Furthermore, you can't do this:

```
double & x() { return coords[0]; }
double & y() { return coords[1]; }
double & z() { return coords[2]; }

double x() const { return coords[0]; }
double y() const { return coords[1]; }
double z() const { return coords[2]; }
```

with the accessors.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd say the first one is better for a few reasons:

- You're unlikely to be performing additional processing mid-get or mid-set on a vertex coordinate.
- Since operations on vertices are usually done very often in loops and vertices are often related to rendering, the first option (direct access) is likely to give you better performance.
- Encapsulation isn't a must if you're going to be directly accessing members with trivial getters and setters.  It's just Object Orientation by dogma.

That being said, the second approach has advantages too, such as an unchanging interface more resilient to change.  I'd still stick with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want direct write access to the members (which it appears you do and *may* be appropriate in this case), then I would suggest the inline functions. This gives you flexibility to profile and inject extra capability into the accesses in the future should you desire to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to remove the reference of the second option and add setters. But if these are the only choices the second would be slightly better.